# Como forçar com que o TTS do Android faça o som do "R" no meio da palavra (como em "caRO"), mas apenas pronunciando o "RO"?

Tags: android, flutter

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo pega as sílabas de um conjunto de palavras, e pronuncia elas sílaba a sílaba, por exemplo "Enfermeiro"="en-fer-mei-ro". **O problema é que se envio apenas o "ro" para o TTS do android sai o som como se fosse um duplo "R" (como em caRRO)** . Não testei ainda no IOS, mas imagino que não seja muito diferente).

No caso de enfermeiro, testei como "en-fer-mei-iro", e funciona, pois fica quase imperceptível o "i" adicional. Mas em alguns casos como por exemplo "CARO", se enviar as sílabas ca-aro, fica muito claro o "a" adicional colocado para forçar o "R" fraco.

**Este alguma forma de indicar para o TTS do android que gostaria que a pronúncia do "ro" seja feita como se fosse o "r" no meio da palavra (como em "ca-RO", "ba-RA-ta", etc)?**

Nota: Eu preciso fazer este som do meio da palavra de forma independente para poder fazer uma animação em cima da palavra enquanto cada sílaba é pronunciada, e pelo TTS não tenho como garantir quando cada sílaba será pronunciada, de forma a permir identificar visualmente  qual parte da palavra está sendo pronunciada.

OBS: estou desenvolvendo em flutter utilizando o pacote flutter_tts: ^3.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente é mais simples do que pensava. Basta usar este XML ao invés do texto:

```
<speak>
    <phoneme alphabet='x-sampa' ph='ro' >ro</phoneme>
</speak>
```

Desta forma, você consegue enviar fonemas ao invés de como a palavra seria falada apenas com aquela sílaba.

X-SAMPA é uma variante do SAMPA, o Alfabeto Fonético Estendido dos Métodos de Avaliação da Fala.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).